# Need Unique Value from table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

Table A

```
ID   Name
1    abc   
2    xyz
```

Table B

```
ID    Name             
1     abc
2     xyz                 
3     mno
```

I need the distinct value form above two table, I mean i want only ID 3 Name mno from Table B (as it is unique from two table)

Please let me know how I can get this value.

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: Depending on the version of SQL Server you are using, you may want to look at [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx?ppud=4).  (As a rule, it is helpful to tag questions with the specific version of SQL Server involved.)

Answer (score 0):

This query will get you the rows from `B` that don't exist in `A`:

```
SELECT b.* FROM TableB b
    OUTER JOIN TableA a ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Name = b.Name
WHERE a.ID IS NULL
```

you could then do the adverse and use a `UNION ALL` to get it both ways:

```
SELECT a.* FROM TableA a
    OUTER JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.ID AND b.Name = a.Name
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT b.* FROM TableB b
    OUTER JOIN TableA a ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Name = b.Name
WHERE a.ID IS NULL
```

---

Another way of achieving it would be:

```
;WITH MatchingRows AS (
    SELECT a.ID FROM TableA a
        JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.ID AND b.Name = a.Name
)
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT m.ID FROM MatchingRows m)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableB
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT m.ID FROM MatchingRows m)
```

I'm not sure if that performs better or not - it's just something I thought of. If I'm not mistaken this will actually run the `WITH` query twice ([see the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838223/is-with-the-replacement-for-a-temp-table)) because it's being used twice - so there may be some performance implications with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The EXCEPT operator may work for you.  Here is an example using your data.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (id int, name varchar(50))
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1, 'abc'),(2,'xyz')

CREATE TABLE TableB (id int, name varchar(50))
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1, 'abc'),(2,'xyz'),(3,'mno')

SELECT * FROM TableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

Be warned though it acts like UNION.  It's only going to exclude rows where there is an exact match on all columns.